# @htmlTextboxFor with Date format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a @Html.TextboxFor and its connected to datepicker class, it also displays a date out a database. How ever it displays the date in the wrong format. When the date is displayed out the DB, that is the only time the date is in the wrong format.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdvertiserSignDate, new { id = "txtAdvDate", @readonly = "true", @class = "DatePicker" })
```

This code below displays the date in the correct format but just on a line below the text box.

```
@(Model == null ? string.Empty : String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", Model.AdvertiserSignDate))
```

I would like to add the formatting of the line above to the first line, so that my textbox displays the date in the correct format and has the function of the date picker.

How can i merge these two lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
@Html.TextBox("AdvertiserSignDate", String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", Model.AdvertiserSignDate), new { id = "txtAdvDate", @readonly = "true", @class = "DatePicker" })
```

Comment: both Html.TextBoxFor() and Html.TextBox generates the same HTML. However Html.TextBoxFor is strongly typed (so if you make any change to model property you will get compile time error notification). BTW: make sure to check that your Model is not null, before accessing the property

Answer (score 2):

try this maybe it helps

```
[DisplayName("Advertiser Sign Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime AdvertiserSignDate { get; set; }

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdvertiserSignDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdvertiserSignDate, new { id = "txtAdvDate", @readonly = "true", @class = "DatePicker", @Value = (Model == null ? string.Empty : Model.AdvertiserSignDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")) })
```

**EDIT**

If `AdvertiserSignDate` is nullable DateTime do this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdvertiserSignDate, new { id = "txtAdvDate", @readonly = "true", @class = "DatePicker", @Value = (Model == null || Model.AdvertiserSignDate == null? string.Empty : Convert.ToDateTime(Model.AdvertiserSignDate).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")) })
```

Comment: This Idea works, but Model.AdvertiserSignDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")) }) is underlined in red

Comment: AdvertiserSignDate property should be of DateTime. Coz DateTime ToString has the overload of string format (in your case I believe AdvertiserSignDate is not of type DateTime; thats why you are getting the red underline) if it is nullable DateTime (see my edited post)